# Does an Intentionally deflated tire incur sidewall damage

Tags: tires

Does a tire the has been intentionally deflated incur damage if it sits that way for a day or two?

Comment: Remove all the air, or just go to a lower pressure?

Comment: Put the car on an axle stand if possible - that way there's no danger to the tyre.

Answer (score 4):

Generally if it just sits there for a relatively short time no damage will occur.  But if you drive it that way, even for a short distance, the damage can occur very quickly.

If it doubt, however, have it inspected by a tire professional.